# Children Fixed positioned element not aligned to Parent Relative positioned element

Tags: html, css, position

I have a `div` which is positioned as relative and whose height is `38px` inside this I have another `div` whose position is set as absolute and the top property is `38px` and the left property is `0`.
 But I can see that from the left its not aligned to the parent element rather it looks as I have set the left property to `1px` which results in a kind of left `1px` margin from the parent element.

So whats really happening?

Comment: Can you create a jsfiidle? It is difficult to troubleshoot without an example.

Comment: Are you sure it's not from the border? http://jsfiddle.net/s4v89/

Comment: @ExplosionPills the both divs have 1px solid #d3d3d3 border

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that's due to the fact that you cannot place child element upon the border of the parent element. so for example if your parent has `border-width:5px` then:
[image]

see? your child div starts exactly after 5px(the width of the border of your parent div), and since it is inside the parent div, it cannot just stand upon the border(sorry for the bad english)it doesnt matters whether you position your element in such a way that it appears outside the parent div, it is still gonna follow the parent-child positioning rule.

**Solution:**

you can either set:

```
left:-1px;
```

or

```
margin-left:-1px;
```

on your child element. Looks hacky but thats all we can do.hope it helps

**Demo** : http://jsfiddle.net/s4v89/1/